# invalid consumer freelancer API

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, api, freelancer.com-api

i am integrating freelancer API into an iOS app and during the authentication process (getRequestToken) , i get the following error:

```
<errors xmlns="http://api.freelancer.com/schemas/xml-0.1">
<error>
    <code>5002</code>
    <msg>General Token Authentication Error</msg>
    <longmsg>Authentication Failed. Reason: invalid consumer</longmsg>
</error>
```

. 
I am appending the query params needed for oauth request within the request URL . The url is http://api.sandbox.freelancer.com/RequestRequestToken/requestRequestToken.json?oauth_callback='oob'&oauth_consumer_key='*****'&oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1'&oauth_signature='V58tFJMmk2%252FI6kcZl1m%252BaA%252FK7Bw%253D'&oauth_timestamp='1337768929'&oauth_nonce='EE982DEB-B6D0-47DD-9193-6CCA3F25446E'&oauth_version='1.0' . Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend you to look at some Oauth library to do the authentication.

For one maybe you can take alook at
http://code.google.com/p/oauth/

This will help you greatly.

Comment: i have already checked the documentation and forum but unable to get any fruitfull result

Comment: I did a quick google and this link came up with code sample and explanation from this it seem that you should have everything you need. Maybe you can post ur codes here. http://developer.freelancer.com/Sample_Code

Comment: i checked that link and that link was of the playground code and not a working sample code for objective c.

Comment: hi developersaremad, i am interested to see if you are looking at 1 to 1 sample to what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am unable to get the sample code for what i am trying to do .